# Count Tasks by department

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

1. I have a table called **Users** that contains the **id**,
   **department_id** and other department attributes.
2. I have a table called **departments** that contains **id** and other
   department attributes.
3. I have a table called **tasks** which has **id** **complated_at**
   and the **user_id**

I would like to know how many tasks were completed by each department

**DepartmentController**

```php
public function index(){ 
        $data = Inertia::render('back/app/departments/index', [
            'filters'  => request()->all('visibility', 'status', 'search'),
            'departments' => Department::orderBy('name')->get(),
            'users_count' => Department::withCount('users')->orderBy('name')->get(),
            'total_tasks' => DB::table('tasks')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'tasks.user_id')
            ->count(),
        ]);
        return $data;
    }
```

**index.vue**

```html
<tr class="border-b border-gray-100 last:border-b-0 hover:bg-gray-50 transition duration-150 ease-in-out" v-for="department in $page.departments">
   <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
    <div class="flex items-center">
     <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10"></div>

      <div class="ml-4">
      <div class="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-900">{{ department.name }}</div>
      <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">print total of completed tasks here</div>
      <span></span>
       </div>
        </div>
      </td>
</tr>
```

Help me please...

Comment: What's your question about this? Is this a Vue problem, or a Laravel problem?

Answer (score 0):

Have you created a Task Model? It looks like you have already done that for Department. If you create a task model (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), you can create a one-to-many relationship between Task and Department and use a count method something like this:

```
$departments = Department::where('x', 'x')->withCount(['tasks as completed_tasks' => function(Builder $query){
$query->whereNotNull('completed_at');
}])->get();
```

Then it will come back in your **$departments** collection as a completed_tasks attribute.

It looks like you might also benefit from creating a relationship between User and Task so you dont have to have a ->join('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'tasks.user_id') in your query.